# How to add two files with the same file name into a single zip archive file?

Tags: android, zip

As from the zip format specification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip, it is possible to add two files with the same file name into a single zip archive file. 
For example, I'd make a zip looks like

```
foo.zip
    --bar.txt
    --bar.txt
    --3rd.txt
```

Does anyone know to accomplish this?
I tried linux utility `zip` and `unzip`, it always overwrites the previous added zip entry. 
The Java class java.util.zip.ZipFile does not work either.

Comment: Sorry where in the specification does it say what you are asking is possible. Android is based on the Unix file system and expects a unique path for a filename

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is to create the zip initially using unique names - e.g. *bar.txt*, *car.txt* and *3rd.txt*. Then open up the resulting zip file in a binary editor and search for *car.txt* and replace it with *bar.txt*.

Note that there should be two occurrences of the filename that you need to replace - one in the local file header for the file (somewhere in the middle of the zip), and one in the central directory (somewhere near the end of the zip).

If you need to do this programmatically, I would suggest you actually parse the central directory to find the exact positions of the filenames in the various headers rather than a simple search and replace to avoid the chance of false positive. It's not a very complicated format.

Note that when you try to uncompress a zip like this, you may get a warning about the file already existing when the second copy of the filename is uncompressed, depending on what program you are using for unzipping and what options you have set.

Comment: I just tried this, using hexeditor to modify the names in the zip-file, worked like a charm!

Comment: Make sure to give all the files names that are the same length. This way you won't have to worry about length fields.